# The color from xml is not the same as for a drawable

Tags: android, colors, android-xml, android-drawable

I need a 1px stroke (yes, physical pixel, not dp) around my `LinearLayout` which I define using an xml shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="1px"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <stroke android:color="@color/lightgray" android:width="1px" />
</shape>
```

And in `colors.xml`

```
<color name="lightgray">#b8b8b8</color>
```

On a different element within the layout, I set a `9-patch` background image and since it also needs a top border of 1px to be consistent with the layout I defined that in the image with the same color. On testing this, the color around the `LinearLayout` is different than what I have defined, it's a much lighter color as seen below in the zoomed version of the 1px border.

[image: incorrect display of color #b8b8b8]
[image: correct display of color #b8b8b8]

The first image displays the border colors defined in xml which should be `#b8b8b8`, the second image is the correct color from the `9-patch` drawable. Now, the funny thing is that if have something larger on screen such as a text the color is displayed correctly. How can I make these two consistent? I'm looking to find out by just how much they differ to make my drawable a lighter version. Or some other solution.

Comment: Perhaps the alpha setting isn't correct? You could try using `#ffb8b8b8` in `colors.xml` and see if that helps.

Comment: @DavidWasser that's still not it unfortunately. It does this for every color, if I want black the actual color I'm getting is `#828282`.